# PresentationCore.dll System.Windows.Media.Imaging BitmapSource.create() returns CachedBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

This code works perfectly outputting a file named output2.tif when I pass a BitmapSource read from a file.

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\PdfVerificationTests.can_use_image_approval_mode.approved.tiff");
    FileStream stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    EncodeImageFromBitmapSource(decoder.Frames[0]);


private void EncodeImageFromBitmapSource(BitmapSource theSource)
{
    //Taken from MSDN
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx
    FileStream stream = new FileStream("output2.tif", FileMode.Create);
    TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
    TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
    myTextBlock.Text = "Codec Author is: " + encoder.CodecInfo.Author.ToString();
    encoder.Frames.Add((BitmapFrame)theSource);
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

This code throws an error

```
private void EncodeImageFromArray(byte[] theSource)
{
    //Taken from Stack Overflow. Purported way to create a BitmapSource from a byte array
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274699/create-a-bitmapimage-from-a-byte-array/15290190?noredirect=1#comment36991252_15290190
    byte[] buffer = new byte[120000]; //changed from "..."
    Buffer.BlockCopy(theSource, 0, buffer, 0, 120000); //added to populate the array from the parameter
    var width = 400; // for example  100 changed to 400
    var height = 300; // for example  100 changed to 300 (400*300*1 = 120000)
    var dpiX = 96d;
    var dpiY = 96d;
    System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray8; // grayscale bitmap  ambiguous PixelFormat reference changed
    var bytesPerPixel = (pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8; // == 1 in this example
    var stride = bytesPerPixel * width; // == width in this example

    BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, pixelFormat, null, buffer, stride);

    //At this point, bitmap should be a BitmapSource??
    EncodeImageFromBitmapSource(bitmap);
}
```

The result of the second function is a runtime error at the `encoder.Frames.Add` line of `EncodeImageFromBitmapSource`:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CachedBitmap' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame'.
```

So when is a `BitmapSource` not a `BitmapSource`? When it's created with `BitmapSource.create()` apparently. The underlying object created by `BitmapSource.create()` is of type `CachedBitmap` and the return is cast to a `BitmapSource`. When I use the BitmapSource in the `encoder.Frames.Add()` function it throws an error. What am I missing?

This is another question, but why is `BitmapSource.create()` returning something that differs in how it's used between the two examples?

Comment: The problem is that you cast a BitmapSource to BitmapFrame. You can obviously only do that when the BitmapSource actually is a BitmapFrame. As a CachedBitmap is not a BitmapFrame, the cast fails. When you decode a BitmapSource from an encoded stream (e.g. from a file), WPF creates an instance of the internal class BitmapFrameDecode, which is a BitmapFrame. Hence the cast succeeds, but only by accident. The cast is in no way legal, you always have to call BitmapFrame.Create().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
encoder.Frames.Add((BitmapFrame)theSource);
```

the bitmapsource type seems cannot just convert to bitmapFrame type
.**(BitmapFrame)theSource** seems will throw exception.
Try

```
BitmapFrame.Create(theSource)
```

Ref:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615993(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615993%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It has no problem when I pass a BitmapSource read from a file. In that instance, the (BitmapFrame) cast works perfectly.

Comment: The answer was to create a BitmapFrame from the CachedBitmap before passing it to the function. A cast works in the first example but not in the second?

Comment: The BitmapSource is an abstract class .CachedBitmap and BitmapFrame are inherit from BitmapSource. I see the example code here also use BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource). [ref-msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms616045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1 It is simply not legal to cast any given BitmapSource to BitmapFrame. It may happen to work by accident, when the BitmapSource actually is a BitmapFrame, but it will obviously fail when this is not the case. Simple answer, **always** use BitmapFrame.Create() when you need to make a BitmapFrame from a BitmapSource.

Comment: So you're admonishing me for doing the same as the library source. The code for BitmapSource.create() returns a CachedBitmap cast as a BitmapSource, and the two aren't directly interchangeable. *That's* why you should qualify your answers containing BitmapSource.create() to warn that it doesn't create a BitmapSource.

Comment: I have removed all comments from your other answer with the exception of the comment pointing to this question.

Comment: @wilsotc You still don't get it, and you are still confusing BitmapImage and BitmapSource. BitmapSource is the **common base class** of BitmapImage and CachedBitmap. You can always cast any of both to their base class BitmapSource. The point in my answer where you are commenting is that you **don't need a BitmapImage at all**. BitmapSource.Create() creates a BitmapSource, but not a (more derived) BitmapImage. But you don't actually need the latter, BitmapSource is sufficient.

Comment: I do understand the inheritance. The CachedBitmap is a BitmapSource pointer with two additional pointers containing attributes. The BitmapFrame inherits BitmapSource with one additional attribute that points to it's thumbnail. A cast works for BitmapSource from CachedBitmap because the BitmapSource is a member of CachedBitmap. The cast to (BitmapFrame) does not work because it requires the creation of the thumbnail attribute. It worked in the first instance because the Thumbnail attribute existed in the object past to the function. Why no error in the code environment? Strict typing?

Comment: That's all wrong. The correct definition is that CachedBitmap is a subclass (or derived class) of BitmapSource, no pointer involved. What you call attributes are actually properties. BitmapSource is also not a member of CachedBitmap. The cast to BitmapFrame doesn't work, but not because is required the "creation of an attribure". It doesn't work because it is **a different class**. You might get a book on C# to learn all these things before you're going to tell people that their
 answers on StackOverflow are wrong. Also please note that you should write @Clemens to address me in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54996/discussion-between-wilsotc-and-clemens).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested.